# Finding a metric in $ \Bbb R^2 $ depending on $s$ such that $x^s+y^s=1$ is a geodesic for all $s$ wrt. the metric

Tags: differential-geometry

Looking for a Riemannian metric or Pseudo-Riemannian metric in $ \Bbb R^2 $ depending on $s$ such that $x^s + y^s = 1$ is a geodesic for all $s$ wrt. the metric. $x,y\in(0,1), s\in \Bbb R(0, \infty). $

Edit: The points at the axes are problematic but they should be fine given the open interval for $x$ and $y$.

Thanks.

Comment: Should this metric be riemannian ? Should $\mathbb{R}^2$ be complete ?

Comment: If you want the metric to be complete on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then, generally, it won't be smooth near the axes, since, when $s\in(1,\infty)$ is not an integer, the curve $x^s+y^s=1$ is not a smooth curve where it meets the axes ($x=0$ or $y=0$).  What kind of regularity are you hoping for for this Riemannian metric?

Comment: Could you make an answer @BenCrowell?

Comment: When I posted my answer, I wasn't sure if I was missing some issue that would make this a research-level question. If not, then I think this is the kind of thing that would have been more suitable for math.SE. Maybe this question should be closed, deleted, or moved to math.SE.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @GeorgeThomas: No worries, it's often difficult for both OPs and others to judge whether a particular question is research level. Sometimes there are issues that aren't clear on a first reading, and something that looks trivial turns out to stump the experts.

Comment: I mean I would be okay if it were moved to math SE

Comment: I do think it's research level however

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if, per the comment, there is no real regularity requirement after all, then I think the following works. Write down a change of coordinates $f$ that takes this curve to the first-quadrant arc of the unit circle, e.g., $f:(x,y)\mapsto (x^{s/2},y^{s/2})$. Write down any metric such that the unit circle is a geodesic, for example $ds^2=dr^2+d\theta^2$. Invert $f$ and transform the metric according to $f^{-1}$.